# Why is vacuum at a critical level in PostgreSQL when I'm running autovacuum?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I just checked the state of vacuum in my PostgreSQL database and it's at a critical level:

```
$ check_postgres --action=last_vacuum
POSTGRES_LAST_VACUUM CRITICAL: DB "postgres" DB: postgres TABLE: pg_catalog.pg_shdepend: 09:22 August 12, 2013 (40 weeks 2 days 4 hours 9 minutes) | time=0.52s postgres.pg_catalog.pg_shdepend=24379780s;86400;172800
```

but I am running autovacuum. Why would this happen?

Comment: I think the better question would be: why does `check_postgres` think that this is critical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check_postgres` isn't very sophisticated software. It just checks if a particular table was vacuumed in the last 2 days (or as configured). For tables with no updates or deletes it is perfectly normal to not be vacuumed for extended periods of time. You can either ignore this or configure `check_postgres` to ignore this particular table.

I don't think this functionality of `check_postgres` is of much use. Maybe for some particular tables. Definitely not so much for system tables like `pg_catalog.pg_shdepend`.